# MySQL check if user has liked photos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a gallery application in Laravel. I have the table users, photos and likes.

```
users
--id
--name
--email

photos
--id
--user_id
--name
--likes
--created_at

likes
--id
--user_id
--photo_id
```

I paginate the photos by 5.

```
SELECT * FROM `photos` order by created_at desc limit 0,5
```

How can I write the query in order to check if the current user has liked these photos without running a separate query for each photo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html). And [`IF()` Control Flow Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) for clear output.

If you are sure that records in table `likes` are unique by `user_id`, then this is enough:

```
SELECT `photos`.*, IF(`likes`.`id` IS NULL, 'no', 'yes') as `he_likes_it`
FROM `photos`
LEFT JOIN `likes` on `likes`.`photo_id` = `photos`.`id` AND `likes`.`user_id` = 123
ORDER BY `photos`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

If you are NOT sure that records in table `likes` are unique by `user_id`, then you need to group the result set, in order to avoid multiplied entries, and use an aggregate function, for example [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

```
SELECT `photos`.*, IF(COUNT(`likes`.`id`) > 0, 'yes', 'no') as `he_likes_it`
FROM `photos`
LEFT JOIN `likes` on `likes`.`photo_id` = `photos`.`id` AND `likes`.`user_id` = 123
GROUP BY `photos`.`id`
ORDER BY `photos`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do joins

```
 SELECT photos.*, count(photos.id) as likes_count FROM `likes`
    LEFT JOIN `photos` ON likes.photo_id = photos.id
    GROUP BY likes.photo_id
    WHERE photos.user_id = 12345
```

Comment: I don't need to get the photos of one specific user I need to check which of the 5 photos are liked by the current user

Comment: @FlorianShena How do you think the query should change then?